# Weird problem, special characters coming after formatting the hard drive, computer isn't starting 0_o

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

Hya friends ,

Last night my computer was working fine. But today when i came back from college and started it , it was starting fine but after sometime it's getting restarted , again and again getting restarted at different points , so i tried to boot it in safe mode but same problem.

Now after all this , i finally decided to format the drive C (it is in 80 GB) and load new OS windows XP3. After formatting (quick format) and loading xp3 sufficient files , when it was getting rebooted for copying the actual os files , it hung  and a weird screen came.

I've also attached the pic of error :

http://www.postimage.org/image.php?v=gxz1vKS

My specs :

1. P4 3.0 Ghz
2. 2 GB RAM (2x 512 mb and 1 GB)
3. 3 hard drives {
   80 GB (5 years old around)
   320 GB ( 2 years old around)
   500 GB ( recently bought)
4. 256 MB graphics card

any help is very appreciated , thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be faulty RAM or a faulty graphics card. To check the RAM you can use [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/), no idea if there is similar software for the graphics card. If you have an old graphics card floating around, you could simply try to use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checks Grumbel has mentioned I would also check the processor fan.

Comment: it isn't heating problem i think, that wouldn't display the special chars which are appearing on screen now.